# Flutter CrCalendar: Events scheduled on border dates (last column) appear as full week event on the next week

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime, calendar

I am using the flutter pub.dev package `cr_calendar` Here is a screenshot of the problem:

[image]

This event is scheduled on the 28th of august, and I am passing the parameter begin & end as the same DateTime.

If I change the first day of the week, and move the event date to the new border date, the same thing happens.
If I add minutes, or event make the end date 23:59 minutes later, same behavior.
If I make both dates UTC, same behavior.
How can I fix this?
I want to note that I am using a repo fork (because I needed some custom fields) so maybe this was fixed already. The fork was created on July 10th 2022.

Here is a link to the issue on their GitHub Repo: [enter link description here](https://github.com/Cleveroad/cr_calendar/issues/11)